# Problems with Getopt::Long and Pod::Usage

Tags: perl

The following is what i have in my perl script. If i run this with arguments, it prints the usage as if @ARGV == 0. Can anyone figure out why?

```
GetOptions (
    'param=s'   => \my $opt_parameter, 
    'o=s'       => \my $opt_o,
    'r=s'       => \my $opt_r,
    'g=s'       => \my $opt_g,
    'len=i'     => \my $opt_rl,
    'ct=i'      => \my $opt_ct,
    'help|?'    => \(my $opt_help = 0),
    'man'       => \(my $opt_man = 0),
) or pod2usage(2); 

pod2usage(1) if $opt_help;
pod2usage(-verbose => 2) if $opt_man;
pod2usage("$0: No files given.") if (@ARGV == 0);
```

Command given:

```
script.pl -o=value1 -r=value2 -g=value3 -len=integervalue1 -ct=integervalue2
```

Comment: Can you please add the command line you're using to invoke the perl script?

Comment: You're not passing in any files to the script. After Getopts has processed the command line arguments there's nothing left in `@ARGV`

Comment: 1) Shouldn't `or pod2usage(2);` be `or die "...";`? 2) Where is `$opt_parameters` used? 3) Do you `use strict; use warnings;`?

Comment: 1. I want to print usage if no arguments are provided. 2. $opt_parameter is optionally used if there is a file with a list of arguments and values. 3. Yes i do use both strict and warnings.

Comment: @Adam - I am passing names of files to $opt_g. Regardless, i believe "@ARGV" holds all arguments if they are provided, which i am doing so there should be something in "@ARGV".

Answer (score 1):

The following works as I assume you want it to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;
use Pod::Usage;

my ($opt_parameter, $opt_o, $opt_r, $opt_g, $opt_rl, $opt_ct);
my $opt_help = 0;
my $opt_man = 0;
my @files;

GetOptions (
        '<>'      =>    sub { push @files, shift },
        'param=s' =>    \$opt_parameter,    
        'o=s'       =>  \$opt_o,
        'r=s'       =>  \$opt_r,
        'g=s'       =>  \$opt_g,
        'len=i'     =>  \$opt_rl,
        'ct=i'      =>  \$opt_ct,
        'help|?' =>     \$opt_help,
        'man'   =>      \$opt_man) or pod2usage(2); 

pod2usage(1) if $opt_help;

pod2usage(-verbose => 2) if $opt_man;

pod2usage("$0: No files given.") if (@files == 0);

print "$_\n" for ( @files );
```

And run it with:

```
-o=value1 -r=value2 -g=value3 --len=1 --ct=2 file1 file2
```

The differences being:

- (Added the shebang and the `use`s.)
- Renamed `$opt_parameters` to `$opt_parameter` (`use strict;` should have caught that).
- **Added a `'<>'` option and `@files` to store [non-option arguments](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt%3a%3aLong#Argument-callback).**
- Look at the size of `@files` instead of `@ARGV`. (The latter has been cleared by `GetOptions()`.)
- (Print `@files` at the end just to see that it worked.)
- Double dashes for long options.
- Give integers to integer type options (`--len` and `--ct`); strings will make parsing fail.
- (Broke lines after `;` to be able to read the code.)

Comment: GetOptions only clears matching options, unmatched args remain in @ARGV

Answer (score 0):

You may be facing this issue.

[**GetOptions does not split the command line correctly**](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)

> The command line is not split by GetOptions, but by the command line
>   interpreter (CLI). On Unix, this is the shell. On Windows, it is
>   COMMAND.COM or CMD.EXE. Other operating systems have other CLIs. It is
>   important to know that these CLIs may behave different when the
>   command line contains special characters, in particular quotes or
>   backslashes. For example, with Unix shells you can use single quotes
>   (') and double quotes (") to group words together. The following
>   alternatives are equivalent on Unix:

- "two words"
- 'two words'
- two\ words

In case of doubt, insert the following statement in front of your Perl program:

> ```
> print STDERR (join("|",@ARGV),"\n");
> ```

to verify how your CLI passes the arguments to the program.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak No. `GetOptions()` will parse `@ARGV`. That line is just declaring some variables.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak I don't see how your *completely changed* answer would apply since OP's command contains neither spaces nor quotes.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out my problem thanks to Adam Taylor. He pointed out that my @ARGV was empty after processing my arguments, which was true. If i put my statement:

```
pod2usage("$0: No files given.") if (@ARGV == 0);
```

Before my GetOptions statement, it works as it is checking @ARGV before the arguments gets passed. Thank you all for helping me troubleshoot!

Comment: Ah, so this was the issue. Accept your own answer so that it's no more in "unanswered" category.

Comment: But if you run your script with `-o value` then `scalar(@ARGV)` will be `2` although no "files" were supplied.

Answer (score -1):

[GetOpt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt%3a%3aLong) parses and removes args from @ARGV.

From the docs:

The Getopt::Long module implements an extended getopt function called GetOptions(). It parses the command line from @ARGV, recognizing **and removing specified options and their possible values.**

Comment: in your case, ANY option is reason enough to pass the test, you definitely want GetOpt::Long to nibble of all VALID parameters at the front, until it's done… Then your @ARGV has the remaining arguments of the command line, usually the files.

Comment: I explained why @ARGV == 0 after the GetOptions(), the command line in the questions doesn't have any other args after options...

Comment: This answer has the same problem as OP's own answer (since they're practically the same): If you run the script with `-o value` then `scalar(@ARGV)` will be 2 although no "files" were supplied.

Comment: Your construction would still workout the thing in a unreliable state, the moment I would pass the arguments `--len=10` it will successfully skip the test at the beginning, the options being nibbled of, leaving @ARGV empty --- You never ever want to inspect your @ARGV before parsing it through GetOpt::Long, that defeats the whole purpose of the module. You definitely want the module to handle all the options first and then deal with the leftovers, like filenames. It was bad advice, sorry to say that